# Material theme from primeng not found

Tags: angular, material-design, primeng

I have an angular app in which I've added the primeng npm, via npm install. As it is stated in the [GetStarted](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup) page from primeng, the library comes with 32 free themes, but within the node_modules/primeng/resources, I only see 8 themes and none of them is material design related theme (e.g. primeng/resources/themes/md-light-indigo/theme.css). I can't seem to find a way to get access on that theme. I want import the primeng/resources/themes/md-light-indigo/theme.css theme, but as mentioned I don't seem to find it in the node_modules/primeng/resources/themes...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check you are on same version as in documentation you are reading.
I just made clean `npm install primeng --save` and it installs v10-rc, which have tone of themes in `node_modules/primeng/resources/themes` including few `md-xxx`

So big chance you installed v9 and reading docs for v10. So or upgrade package or read docs for v9 - https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v9.1.4-lts/#/setup

Comment: Stupid mistake, didn't thought of that. Thank you!